# What's the syntax for CKEDITOR.replaceAll custom assertion functions?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, assert, assertions, assertion

I would like to selectively avoid replacing textareas with CKEDITOR.replaceAll.  I cannot simply use replace instead.  I must use custom assertion functions mentioned in the documentation.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll

```
// Selectively replace <textarea> elements, based on custom assertions.
CKEDITOR.replaceAll( function( textarea, config ) {
    // An assertion function that needs to be evaluated for the <textarea>
    // to be replaced. It must explicitely return "false" to ignore a
    // specific <textarea>.
    // You can also customize the editor instance by having the function
    // modify the "config" parameter.
} );
```

But there is no `assert` in javascript.  What's the syntax for the assertions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of "assertion function" in the [CKEDITOR documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll) is misleading.  There is no `assert` in javascript.  Just use a conditional and `return false` to ignore a specific `textarea`.

Example:

```
CKEDITOR.replaceAll(function (textarea, config) {
    if (textarea.classList.contains("ignore_me")) {
        return false;
    };
    <...>
});
```

Comment: You're totally right, thanks for pointing this out. I've [just fixed this](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/806c40832c81d5ffedab2c72788d352052502c5f#diff-d0c2cb93caeb33d1d59fd2506921ea4aL82) is our docs, this will probably be updated online in a few days. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnnaTomanek Happy to help. Thanks for fixing the docs so quickly!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. We truly care about our documentation and wholeheartedly welcome feedback such as this. The team was really happy to send a few upvotes as a small "thank you" note :) Again, sorry about any inconvenience caused!

Comment: @AnnaTomanek We use CKEDITOR a lot around here.  We appreciate your product and attention to detail.  :)